# Report formular column showing object where not in object

Tags: business-objects

I'm trying to filter a report in business objects,

I'm mostly where I want to be from multiple queries being run and custom variable in the report.

What I'm struggling with is creating a column that displays `[AccountID A]` that is not in `[AccountID B]`.

These account ID's came from the same object but are different lists from the run queries

example Formula attempt for column

```
=[AccountID A] where ([AccountID A] <> [AccountID B])
```

This comes up with no entries however and I know from exporting and filtering my test batch in excel there are 3 ID's that should display. Also been attempting variations with `NOT`, and variation with `INLIST` with no luck so far, anyone able to suggest an approach?

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest approach would be to create a **query filter** specifying that [AccountID A] Not in List [AccountID B]. You have to choose "Results from another query" so you have something like this.

Does that work for you?

Noel

[image]

Comment: Whenever I have tried to filter from a previous query its never successfully (manually) run, Ive managed to get the ultimate outcome I wanted now reversed the query and then worked some report level joins and filters. It means ive initially pulled a lot more results than wanted but it works to get the final result I want.